# How do I customize the login form on a WordPress site to allow users to view and hide their password?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, authentication, passwords, customization

The login form on my WordPress site (version 5.2.5) is customized using the ‘Theme My Login’ plugin (version 6.4.9).

When I access my login page http://staging.alphaprofit.com/log-in-or-register/ in Microsoft Edge Version 81.0.416.64, I see the ‘eye icon’.

The ‘eye icon’ allows users to toggle between viewing and hiding their passwords.

The ‘eye icon’ however does NOT display when I access the same login page with Chrome or Firefox.

To enable the ‘eye icon’ in Chrome and Firefox, I did the following:

I took the lines of code from w3schools.org https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp and added them to the Theme My Login file login-form.php at http://staging.alphaprofit.com/wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/templates/login-form.php

```
<div class="tml-rememberme-submit-wrap">
<p class="tml-rememberme-wrap">
<input name="showpwdchkbox" type="checkbox" id="showpwdchkbox<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" onclick="myFununction()" />
<label for="showpwdchkbox<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Show Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFununction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("user_pass");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>
```

The ‘Show Password’ checkbox appears in both Chrome and Firefox when the above code is used.

The checkbox toggle, however, does NOT function. It does not hide or show the password. The toggle is basically dead.

How should I fix this issue so that users can view and hide their password in all major browsers like Chrome, Safari, Edge, and Firefox?

**Update**

Thanks for your help. I checked the plugin code. It has the input password field placed just above the code I sent you previously:

```
<p class="tml-user-pass-wrap">
<label for="user_pass<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Password', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off" />
<a href="../lostpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
</p>
```

The Javascript code gets executed through the following lines in the child theme’s functions.php file:

```
function load_js_tml_loginformpage() {
if (is_page(6527)) {
wp_enqueue_script('my-jvsc', 'http://staging.alphaprofit.com/wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/templates/ummy-js.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_tml_loginformpage');
```

Right now, the javascript file “ummy-js.js” has the following lines of code. This code works just for the first instance “user_pass1”:

```
function myFununction() {var x = document.getElementById("user_pass1");
if (x.type === "password") {x.type = "text";} else {x.type = "password";
}
}
```

Referring to http://staging.alphaprofit.com/log-in-or-register/,  the above Javascript code has 2 issues:

1)  In Firefox, when the user starts typing the first few characters of the password in the login page, the page seems to refresh itself. This takes a few seconds before the user can continue typing the full password. Is there a way to stop this autorefresh and delay? This problem does Not appear to manifest in Chrome.

2)  The password field’s ID in the plugin includes the instance value, e.g., “user_pass1” or “user_pass2” and so on. Currently, the Javascript code I have added checks for only ID=“user_pass1”.  What is Javascript syntax to check for multiple instances, i.e., checking for “user_pass#” (where #=1, 2,3, and so on) instead of “user_pass1” alone.

```
function myFununction() {
var x = document.getElementById("user_pass1");
if (x.type === "password") {
x.type = "text";
} else {
x.type = "password";
}
}
```

Comment: Update your WP Version and you'll see it... It's part of core. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/10/wordpress-5-3-adds-a-show-button-next-to-the-password-field-on-the-login-screen/

Comment: @Howarde Thanks for letting me know. This is helpful. I am, however, unable to update the WordPress version on this site quickly due to other non-compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an input field for the password and give it the right ID.

```js
function myFununction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("user_pass");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tml-rememberme-submit-wrap">
  <p class="tml-rememberme-wrap">
    <input name="showpwdchkbox" type="checkbox" id="showpwdchkbox" onclick="myFununction()" />
    <label for="showpwdchkbox">Show</label>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
<input type="password" id="user_pass">
</div>
```

Comment: I have additional information and code I would like to share. How do I add them to this thread?