# how to add a toggle for visibility in theme my login WP plugin

Tags: wordpress, passwords, visibility

I would really like to add a checkbox or an eye icon to toggle password visibility on the Theme My Login registration and login forms on mystery-solvers.com (not live yet).

I read responses in another [thread] ([How do I customize the login form on a WordPress site to allow users to view and hide their password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447073/how-do-i-customize-the-login-form-on-a-wordpress-site-to-allow-users-to-view-and))on this subject, but some things have changed in the plugin over the last years. There now is a Using theme-my-login-custom.php that can be used and some other things have changed too.

I am not a developer so the instructions on the plugin's [documentation](https://docs.thememylogin.com/collection/10-advanced-topics.com) are beyond reach for me.

I tried adding the code from the other tread to the theme-my-login-custom.php file but it shows up in the wrong place and it wasn't not working.

I looked on https://www.alphaprofit.com/log-in-or-register/ using Chrome inspector to try to copy what they did, but I didn't succeed.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot.